# StoreKit.isSupported returning false on iOS device

Tags: ios, storekit

I've recently purchased the Milkman StoreKit native extension for in-App purchasing on iOS. I'm having issues with initialising the StoreKit on my iPhone 4S.

I've followed the instructions in the Milkman games example and my code looks like this:

```
log("Is Supported " + StoreKit.isSupported());    
if(StoreKit.isSupported())
{   
    StoreKit.create();
    log("StoreKit Initialized.");

    // make sure that purchases will actually work on this device before continuing!
    // (for example, parental controls may be preventing them.)
    if (!StoreKit.storeKit.isStoreKitAvailable())
    {
        log("Store is disable on this device.");
        return;
    }
}
```

The docs for the StoreKit.isSupported() function says the following:

```
isSupported ()  method   
public static function isSupported():Boolean
Checks if the current platform supports StoreKit. Note that this only determines whether the app is running under iOS (as opposed to Android, Windows, etc.) Use this call before initializing StoreKit in order to confirm that you are on iOS. (So that you can avoid initializing StoreKit on an unsupported platform when building a multi-platform app.)

Returns
Boolean — true if StoreKit is supported; false otherwise.
```

When i run my app from Flash Builder on my laptop the Storekit.isSupported() function returns false (as expected as it is not an iOS device). However when i build an IPA and deploy to my iPhone 4, it STILL returns false, although I have a WiFi connection and checked that I do not have any restrictions on IAP on my phone.

Has anyone had the same problem and solved it or does anyone have any suggestions on what I might try next?

Many thanks

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken ?

Comment: I had the same problem when I didn't include the ane extension properly.